# Kafka server giving Error Shutdown broker on start up

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using kafka_2.11-2.1.0 where I started zookeeper server, kafka server, created topics and sent messages.

Later next day when I tried to follow the same steps, it gave error as:

```
ERROR shutdown broker because all log dirs in C:\Kafka-logs have failed
```

while starting kafka server.

I tried to delete the old topic as well but it did not get deleted and tried to restart the server. It starts, gives the above error and shuts down immediately. I even tried deleting the complete logs and restarted the server. This time my server did not show up!!

Comment: Could you attach part of logs?

Comment: Looks like this can be related -- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6188. (I assume you're running on Windows.)

Comment: @mazaneicha I saw the link you shared, I have exactly the same issue. Not sure about the solution. Although, I tried to re-install kafka and started servers but issue still persists. Please suggest a solution!!

Comment: @wardziniak I am facing same issue as issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6188 and I am running on windows.

Comment: In general, Linux is more heavily tested against. Sorry to say, but Kafka in Docker or a VM would work better